# Max number of covariates in lm()

Tags: r

I use lm() to analysis data with 16 covariates. However i can only get 9 coef, the coef of v9-v16 is NA.

```
coef <- coef(lm(y~v1+v2+v3+...+v16,data=df))
```

I check if i only use 8 covariates, then i can get all coef.

```
coef <- coef(lm(y~v1+v2+v3+...+v8,data=df))
```

or

```
coef <- coef(lm(y~v9+v10+v11+...+v16,data=df))
```

Why is NA? and how to analysis more than 8 covariates? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is not a maximum number of covariates in `lm()`. For more help you'll need to revise your post: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: it is extremely likely that some of your covariates are perfectly collinear with others.

Answer (score 1):

This is too messy for a comment, but basically is one.

Try:

```
set.seed(12039)
NX <- 20
DF <- as.data.frame( matrix(rnorm(100*NX), ncol = NX))
DF$y <- rnorm(100)

lm(y~., data = DF)
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ ., data = DF)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)           V1           V2           V3           V4           # V5           V6           V7           V8  
#   -0.059471     0.038887    -0.024053    -0.131015    -0.086795    # -0.159099    -0.269060     0.099055    -0.092254  
#          V9          V10          V11          V12          V13          # V14          V15          V16          V17  
#   -0.080832     0.006313     0.068917    -0.030187     0.279635     # 0.038846    -0.071679     0.112288    -0.007563  
#         V18          V19          V20  
#    0.030256     0.163070     0.020152
```

You can try `NX = 100` or `NX = 10000` if you're still not convinced -- `lm` doesn't have a "limit" on the number of covariates, *per se*. There's something else going on with your regression, as hinted in the other comments.